# VLC Android Crash Accessing Server, VLC Windows Accesses Same Server Successfully - New Server NIC

Tags: vlc

I have a network machine running Windows 10 Pro with a folder shared public. This server has been accessed by both VLC Android & VLC Windows on this network without issues for years.
I upgraded the network card to a TrendNET 10gbit TEG-10GECTX v3. Windows still accesses it fine, as does VLC for Windows(v3.0.18), however all Android VLC devices - Firestick(v3.5.4) & Android Phone(v3.5.4) - crash now when trying to access that server from the network.
I tried upgrading the NIC driver to latest Marvell AQTion driver v 3.1.7. I've tried turning on CIFS on the Windows machine and setting the share to full public (not require logonid/pw) and I've also force-stopped the VLC Android apps, cleared all data, uninstalled/reinstalled VLC and tried turning off the PREFER SMB 1 setting. The Windows share security is set to Everyone - Full Access. All of this has been done to no avail - crashes the VLC Android versions every single time.

Anyone have any other suggestions? As a last resort I will try a XG-C100C 10gbit NIC by Asus.

Comment: On Android side: Have you checked `adb logcat` for errors or more details what is going wrong?